# .NET 4.0 in C++ - How call AppendText for RichTextBox from a static member function

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++, richtextbox, static-functions

My mind somehow is stuck in a "loop of errors". I don't want to waste time any more with endless trial and error, so I better ask here:

I have a Windows-Form (.NET, C++) like following. The simplified version here only has a RichTextBox, a static and a non-static member function. Appending Text to the RichTextBox from the non-static function "**nonstaticFunc()**" works as expected.

But how can I do this from the static member function "**staticFunc()**"? I tried several approaches proposed in this forum on how to call non-static functions from static functions, but somehow I couldn't figure out how to do this.

```
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {

    public:
        Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    protected:
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    protected: 

    private:
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

    private: System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^  myTextBox;




    System::VoidInitializeComponent( System::Void )
    {
        System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(Form1::typeid));
        this->myTextBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox());
    }

    public: System::Void nonstaticFunc( System::Void )
    {
        this->myTextBox->AppendText( L"Append this...\n" );
    }

    public: static System::Void staticFunc( System::Void )
    {
        // How do I AppendText here??
        // Not working: this->myTextBox->AppendText( L"Append this...\n" );
    }
}
```

Thanks for every little bit of help! Appreciated a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work out *which* text box you're interested in. What if there are two visible forms? You don't have enough context.

Now you *could* keep a static member to keep track of "the one true form" - or you could take the textbox or form as a parameter... but fundamentally you need to have that context *somehow*.

Why do you want to do this from `staticFunc` anyway? Why can the caller not call the method on the appropriate form? Once you understand the problem - why it won't work - you should be able to think about the most appropriate change. We can't really tell you that, as we don't have enough information.

Comment: OK right, wasn't clear enough on that. I have only one instance of that form - your so called "(the) one true form".

I tried your second idea: passing the form as a parameter. But how can I pass on a reference to the form inside a non-static function? I obviously can not use "this".

Comment: @EliteTUM: You haven't shown what's calling this in the first place. Basically you should have all the context you need - or if you *really* need to, you can just have a static variable, as I suggested in the middle paragraph. In the constructor, set the value of that static variable to "this", and you'll be able to get back to "the one true form" at any time. And then everything will break when your assumption changes, of course...

Comment: I am using an  System::Timers::Timer^ myTimer. Following the Example on MSDN I made it static as well as the Function being called when the Elapsed-Event rises. So that's why I tried doing this within "staticFunc".

Comment: @EliteTUM: The event handler *can* be static, but it doesn't *have* to be. The best solution here is just to use an instance method as the event handler...

Comment: :In my approaches before I tried the solution to introduce a _static variable_ (let's say) `statForm` and setting it to `this` in the constructor (`statForm = this`). Accessing the **RichTextBox** with `statForm->myTextBox->AppenText(L"Test\n")` works perfectly within non-static functions. But trying this within static-functions either stops the execution of the function or even makes the application crash. I'll revise my code and try to replace all static functions, hopefully that will help. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @EliteTUM: Well, it would be worth understanding *why* it was crashing before. I don't have any experience in C++/CLI, but it *should* be okay.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Debugger won't give me any Information on WHY it crashes. The Application just exits. Nevertheless, I - somehow - followed your advice and got rid of all static functions and variables and now it - of course - works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @EliteTUM: Well if you put a breakpoint on the line which is going to go bang, can you check whether statForm is non-null for example? Anyway, glad the fix worked...